# allow domain only for certain extensions with hatccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain abc.com

with subdomains

```
abc.com
www.abc.com
img.abc.com
```

All pointing to the same folder on my server.

Since I intend to use img.abc.com as a cdn, need to prevent img.abc.com/pqr.html from being a duplicate of www.abc.com/pqr.html.

ie

```
abc.com/* should redirect to www.abc.com/*
img.abc.com/*.jpg/gif/png should be allowed
[img.abc.com/*.other extension] should be redirected to [www.abc.com/*.other extension]
```

What could be the possible htaccess rules to be included?

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# abc.com/* should redirect to www.abc.com/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R]

# img.abc.com/*.jpg/gif/png should be allowed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [L,NC]

# [img.abc.com/*.other extension] should be redirected to [www.abc.com/*.other extension]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R]
```